On a generic point for a simple measure on F2
I was wondering if someone has any idea on how to attack this: Let's say I have the free group on two generators: $F=<a,b>$ and I put a prob. measure $\mu=c_1\delta_a+c_2\delta_b +c_3\delta_{a^{-1}}+c_3\delta_{b^{-1}}$ on $F$. Consider the measure $\mu^\mathbb{N}$ on $G=F^\mathbb{N}$ where all $c_i\neq 0$. I think that a generic point $\omega=\left(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots\right)$ is such that $S_n(\omega)= \omega_1\circ \omega_2\circ\dots \omega_n$ length is unbounded (i.e. that there are not that many reductions to keep this length bounded). Am I wrong?
